# How do I modify my cloth sim to respect the ground plane?

Tags: cloth-simulation

My desired end-goal is simple: I just want my cloth sim to relax naturally and hit the ground plane. But here is my result:
[image]

Relevant facts:

- Working in Blender 3.5
- Both the curtain and the curved ground plane are just loaded with geometry.
- The curved ground plane has clear thickness, but the 'cloth' plane does not have a solidify effect or anything.
- The 'curtain' has the cloth modifier applied with the default 'Cotton' preset.
- The curved ground plane has the Rigid Body effect applied (Collision set to Mesh)

No matter how much I tweak variables, I cannot cause the curtain to respect the ground plane and am sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks very much for your attention.

Comment: please provide blend file because you didn't provide any settings you made. thx

Comment: You don't need Rigid Body for plane ... Use [Collision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/collision.html) instead from the same physics panel.